# URL Amigável mudando link de arquivos

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte url amigável

```
RewriteRule ^noticias/([0-9]+)/?$ inicio.php?pg=noticias&id=$1
```

Porem quando eu acesso meusite.com.br/noticias/14

Ele muda os links dos arquivos para

```
noticias/css/principal.css
```

sendo que o original é

```
/css/principal.css
```

E quando eu acesso o link sem a url amigavel exemplo

```
meusite.com.br/inicio.php?pg=noticias&id=$1
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o seu CSS deve esta com um caminho relativo e será interpretado a partir da última barra do endereço da página

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/principal.css"/>
```

Dessa forma dependendo de qual página abrir o endereço pode ser interpretado de diferentes formas:

- `http://meusite.com.br/noticias/css/principal.css`
- `http://meusite.com.br/css/principal.css`

Para contornar o problema existem duas soluções:

#### 1- colocar o endereço completo no CSS

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meusite.com.br/css/principal.css"/>
```

#### 2- Utilizar o elemento HTML [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Para configurar a referência base de todos os links (CSS, JS, links e imagens)

```
<base href="http://meusite.com.br/"/>
```

Desse modo, todos os caminhos relativos não vão depender do endereço da página.

Answer (score 2):

Você atualmente está inserindo o seu arquivo CSS de maneira relativa, ou seja, assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/principal.css">
```

Mas em casos de URL amigável você deve colocar o CSS (e outros assets como js e imagens) usando um caminho absoluto, que no caso seria assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meusite.com.br/css/principal.css">
```

Isso ocorre porque o navegador vai entender a URL amigável como um diretório, e vai acabar buscando o CSS dentro desse diretório que não existe...